# Is it possible to create a simple Login Application using java swings on a network of two computer?

Tags: java, swing

i am testing some scenarios here. I have a simple login application with a backend mySQL Database on my windows laptop. It is working fine. I am using `JDBC-ODBC Driver` for connectivity.

I was thinking that is it possible that my java swing application can communicate with my same application on a second connected computer through wifi or LAN.
I want something like a central sort of database on one system and other connected system should use this central database.

I seriously don't know how to achieve this. On a single system this is very easy but how to achieve this with multiple systems is totally another thing

**Scenario** ->

- Database on PC1
- Java Swing Application on PC2 - When trying to Login , data should
  come from the database on PC1

Comment: Very much possible, what is the challenge?

Comment: This is the challenge..I can make a login app on a single pc, but on multiple computers and a single database, hw shall i communicate with it?

Comment: @JunedAhsan - Can you help me if it is possible?

Comment: Use a real JDBC driver, and use the appropriate URL to connect to the database. If you said what your database is, it would be easier to help.

Comment: I know theoretically how to do it. It's just that i have never done this sort of thing so i don't know how to proceed. Thanks anyways